# How to fix file corruption from downloaded video

Tags: python, video, corruption

I'm trying to write a downloader for

> https://www.southpark.de

I got the master.m3u8 but if I try to download one part of the episode like

> https://cc-l3.ts.mtvnservices.com/gsp.comedystor/com/sp/season-6/0605/acts/0/seg_384x216_293938_66.ts

it says the file is corrupted how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

The file is not corrupted. Its encrypted. You can't "fix" it because it's not broken. And you can't decrypt it unless you know the decryption key.